# Getting row id from database by clicking listview after deleting record

Tags: android, database, listview

I have created a database with 5 columns id , name , date , month and year.
it is getting created perfectly, i am able to put it in a list view.
Now the problem is that when i delete a record from the database. I am not
able to get the correct row id to work on(delete or edit it).because the list view does not point to the database , only shows the strings from there in a list view.

is there a way that after i remove a record i can still get the correct row id to work on.
i want to get the row id of the record when clicked in the list view..

Get data function used in database to send the 5 items to the display activity

```
public ArrayList<String> getData() {

    String[] columns = new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, KEY_DATE,
            KEY_MONTH, KEY_YEAR };

    Cursor c = db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null,
            null);
    String result = "";

    int iRow = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);
    int iName = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME);
    int iDate = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_DATE);
    int iMonth = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_MONTH);
    int iYear = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_YEAR);
    ArrayList<String> string_array = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {
        result = c.getString(iRow) + " " + c.getString(iName) + "\t\t"
                + c.getString(iDate) + "\t\t" + c.getString(iMonth)
                + "\t\t" + c.getString(iYear) + "\n";
        string_array.add(result);

    }
    return string_array;
}
```

call for string array in the display activity

```
 ArrayList<String> data = db.getData();
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, data);
    lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

Getting the row id after first elements from database are deleted

```
  public long getFROWID() {
    String[] columns = new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, KEY_DATE,
            KEY_MONTH, KEY_YEAR };

    Cursor c = db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null,
            null);
    c.moveToFirst();
    int iRow = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);
    ROWID = c.getString(iRow);
    long value = Long.parseLong(ROWID);
    return value;
}
```

Function in the database class to get the first row id after record is deleted

```
  @Override
public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View listview,
        int position, long id) { 
    IMPID = db.getFROWID() + id;
    openContextMenu(lv);
    return true;
}
```

Update using simple adapter

```
  String[] from = { BdayDatabase.KEY_NAME };
    int[] to = { R.id.item_name };

    List<HashMap<String, String>> listinfo = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    listinfo.clear();

        HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();
        hm.put("name" , BdayDatabase.KEY_NAME);
        listinfo.add(hm);


    SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, listinfo, R.layout.item_layout, from, to);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why dont you make the listview bind to the database instead of creating an array list???

that way all you need to do is have your primary key as `_id` for it to bind to the listview correctly. Then when you click on a row, the `long id` variable is the id of the item you clicked in the database

Comment: i will try doing that...can you point me to a good example you know??
and i found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4520524/binding-listview-row-with-sqlite-database-for-custom-rows

Comment: all you have to do is instead of using `ArrayAdapter`, you use `SimpleAdapter` but while you are doing that I would look into using `Loaders` with your database

Comment: there is no way I am going to be able to read that...update your question

Comment: oh sorry I meant you need to use `SimpleCursorAdapter` my fault. basically you should not be doing anything with an array list anymore and dealing only with cursors

Comment: :O no problem....but there is a problem using simpleCursorAdapter, i tried using that but it is available on API 11+ only and i want to support gingerbread also

Comment: simple cursor adapter is also available in the support library so you can still use is

Comment: import android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter; do i have to import this to use it?

Comment: ok i tried using it, and it working now maybe i used the wrong library last time, so is the listview linked to the database now??

Comment: as long as you renamed the primary key column to `_id`; yes it should be. you can test this bu putting a breakpoint in the listItemClick method and seeing if the id varible is the id you expect it to be

Comment: and one more thing...what should i do about the loaders

Comment: think about using them in the future because the query is executed in a separate thread but you need to use a ContentProvider with loaders and it dose not look like you currently are. Do you have to use them..no but it is highly recommended because its easier to manage, query is done in separate thread and your list gets updated automatically when your database is updated

Comment: alright i will try that sometime later then... thank you for the help :)